# How to programatically change the input value of a component which was already rendered (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angular2-components

In my Angular 2 app I have a component (mainComp) which includes another one via

```
 <my-comp></my-comp>
```

**my-comp** emits (on select / click) it's value (it's a custom dropdown) via

```
this.optionSelected.emit(currentOption == "Not described" ? null : currentOption);
```

`mainComp` receives the value of the dropdown by

Comment: Good question! The @Input value can be changed by assigning a value to the input property

Comment: @AngJobs can you please provide an example in an actual answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a 2-way-binding, so if the object changes, the result should also be refreshed. If you've got an EventEmitter, subscribe in the constructor like:

```
class MainComp {
  let value;
  ...
  constructor(private myComp : MyComp) {
    myComp.optionSelected.subscribe{
      (value) => this. value = value;
    }
}
```

Now, everytime the EventEmitter fires emit, the value-attribute in MainComp will be updated.

If you want to something facy, take a look at ngOnChanges (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

**Update**:
Do you mean sth. like this:

```
class MainComp {
  template: `<myComp [(value)]=value></myComp>`
  ...
}

class MyComp {
  @Input(): value;
  ...
}
```

This should create a 2-way-binding, so if one of the Components edits value, the other gets notified.
Take a look at this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel

Comment: (I couldn't check today but I'll do soon and eventually accept the answer!)

Comment: I hope it works! [()] creates a two-way-binding, but you can also use only [] or (), if you do not want this binding (e.g. thats what you are doing subscribing to an event with ($event) ).

Comment: honestly that was a part of a feature we decide to remove just yesterday from the project so I couldn't really test it. however it makes perfectly sense, that's why I accepted the answer

Comment: @bene any ideas about update [(ngModel)] when I set the [(value)]?